# Layout changes when dynamic activity is started

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dynamic

I have a layout which allows for a dynamic EditText to be created - this works fine but it pushes up the static EditTexts which is not what I want.

I am using a scrollview so in theory the static EditText should anchor in place and when the dynamic EditTexts are added, the user can just scroll down.

Instead, the 3 static EditTexts I have start moving closer and closer together as more dynamic EditTexts are added. The spacing in the dynamic EditTexts are spacing fine as they are all part of the same array, but I can't seem to see whats happening with the static EditTexts.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/facebookBlue"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:context="com.test.practise.AddTeamMembers">


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tv_teamNames"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/teamName"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.26"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.47"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Enter Player Names Below!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </FrameLayout >


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/et_team_name1"
                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/PlayerName"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="76dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp"
                />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_team_name2"
                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/PlayerName"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="76dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp"
                />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_team_name3"
                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/PlayerName"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="76dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/editTextGroupLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.07"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_add_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+ Add Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </FrameLayout >


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_submit_team"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/facebookBlue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ready to join!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </FrameLayout >


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Which results in this

[image: Before Dynamic EditText is added]

[image: After Dynamic EditText is added]

Comment: Why are you wrapping every widget inside of a FrameLayout?  That seems useless.  `android:orientation="vertical"` does nothing for a FrameLayout.  Also, you have a dead LinearLayout in your layout definition.  Try removing `android:weightSum="1"` from both your parent LinearLayout and any children, you don't seem to be using weights correctly.

Comment: Ah yeah the orientation was left in there by mistake as I was using Linear Layouts - just experimenting really. As for the 'dead LinearLayout' this is referenced in my code as part of the dynamic EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing all of your code, but I believe your problem stems from the use of `android:fillViewport` on your `ScrollView` and `android:layout_weight` on your `LinearLayout`'s children.

Your `ScrollView`'s child, the `LinearLayout`, has `wrap_content` height. However, due to the `fillViewport` attribute on the `ScrollView`, your `LinearLayout` will be stretched to fill the screen. This means there is going to be some "extra" height.

The `layout_weight` attributes divide up that extra height, and give some of it to each child.

As you dynamically add `EditText`s to your view, the amount of height that is "extra" is reduced (until there is no extra height). This has the visual effect of pushing your original views closer and closer together.

The solution will depend on exactly what you want to achieve. I suspect that the answer is that you should remove the `layout_weight` attributes from your views, and instead use margins to separate them visually.

Comment: Yes, it was the `layout_weight` attributes causing the problem, everything is working as it should now, thanks!